# How to avoid stack overflow in this code, (Recursive function)

Tags: c++, recursion, stack-overflow

I was trying to solve a programming contest problem. I am pretty much a noob in this department (I think I have a lot to learn). I tried to solve the question, which included reading a 2D array(`n x m`) and finding out the blobs in it. Blobs are formed by contiguous lit pixels(denoted by `#`). Unlit pixels (denoted by `.`). I tried to find a blob by using a recursive method `Blob::form()`. Sample input might look like this

```
1
6 6
#...#.
.#.#.#
##..#.
......
.#.#.#
#...#.
```

I came up with the solution in a rush. And it's not much. But as always it fails in the worst condition `n = m = 1000` and all chars are `#`. A 1000 x 1000 version of this:

```
1
3 3
###
###
###
```

The problem I assume is stack overflow. I have found out that the program is crashing while forming the blob.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int pat[1000][1000],n,m;
char a[1000][1000];

struct point
{
    int x,y;
};

bool inBounds(point p)
{
    if(p.x < n && p.x >=0 && p.y < m && p.y >= 0) return true;
    else return false;
}
bool isAblob(int i,int j)
{
    point p[8];
    p[0].x = i-1; p[0].y =  j;
    p[1].x = i+1; p[1].y =  j;
    p[2].x = i+1; p[2].y =  j+1;
    p[3].x = i-1; p[3].y =  j-1;
    p[4].x = i-1; p[4].y =  j+1;
    p[5].x = i+1; p[5].y =  j-1;
    p[6].x = i; p[6].y =  j-1;
    p[7].x = i; p[7].y =  j+1;

    for(int k=0;k<8;k++)
    {
        if(inBounds(p[k]))
        {
            if(a[p[k].x][p[k].y] == '#') return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


class Blob
{
public:
    long long int pow;

    Blob(int i, int j)
    {
        this->pow = 0;
        point po;
        po.x=i;
        po.y=j;
        this->form(&po);
    }

    int getPow()
    {
        return this->pow;
    }

    void form ( point *p)
    {
        if(inBounds(*p))
        {
            if(a[p->x][p->y] == '#' && !pat[p->x][p->y])
            {
                a[p->x][p->y] = 1;
                this->pow++;
                point *e = new point;
                e->x = p->x-1; e->y =  p->y;if(pat[e->x][e->y] == 0)form(e);
                e->x = p->x+1; e->y =  p->y;if(pat[e->x][e->y] == 0)form(e);
                e->x = p->x+1; e->y =  p->y+1;if(pat[e->x][e->y] == 0)form(e);
                e->x = p->x-1; e->y =  p->y-1;if(pat[e->x][e->y] == 0)form(e);
                e->x = p->x-1; e->y =  p->y+1;if(pat[e->x][e->y] == 0)form(e);
                e->x = p->x+1; e->y =  p->y-1;if(pat[e->x][e->y] == 0)form(e);
                e->x = p->x; e->y =  p->y-1;if(pat[e->x][e->y] == 0)form(e);
                e->x = p->x; e->y =  p->y+1;
                if(pat[e->x][e->y] == 0)form(e);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int t;

    cin >> t;
    for (int q = 0; q < t; q++)
    {
        cin >> n >> m;
        int bnum = 0;
        Blob *b[(n*m)/2];
        vector <int> pows;
        cin.get();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<m;j++)
            {
                a[i][j] = cin.get();
                pat[i][j] = 0;
            }
            cin.get();
        }


        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<m;j++)
            {
                if(a[i][j] == '#' && pat[i][j] == 0)
                {
                    if(isAblob(i,j))
                    {
                        bnum++;
                        b[bnum] = new Blob(i,j);
                        pows.push_back(b[bnum]->getPow());
                    }
                    else continue;
                }
                else continue;
            }
        }
        sort(pows.begin(),pows.end());
        cout << endl << bnum;

        for(int i=1;i<=bnum;i++)
        {
            if(i==1) cout << endl;
            if(i!=1) cout << " ";
            cout << pows[i-1];
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure my code is buggy and inefficient. I am wondering if someone can give me an insight on how to avoid these problems in the future. Better implementations can be helpful too. But what I am looking for are tips for avoiding stack overflows in the future.

Comment: I can think of turning your recursive functions into loops, making sure they are tail-recursive (and rely on the compiler to optimize them) or choosing bigger base-cases for divide and conquer algorithms. For instance, in your method `form`, I have the feeling you're doing a BFS (breadth first search, seeing the grid as a graph) (Edit: actually that's a DFS, but you can also turn that into a loop and a list). Instead of a recursive function, you could probably turn that into a loop which updates a list of neighbour points and pop the first element at each iteration.

Comment: @Caninonos I'll try that. You think that could possibly avoid the stack overflow, since we limit function calls?

Comment: Yup. The key is that your list structure will (likely) store its objects in the heap instead of the stack (Edit: by "likely", I mean: you can certainly make a list structure reserving memory on the stack, but that would be weird, dynamic data structures usually use the heap). (Also, in this specific case, I'd prefer a BFS rather than a DFS, I think it should make the list grow a bit less in some extreme cases)

Comment: `e` is constructed but never deleted.  `bnum` is used from 1 on up -- ie., `bnum` == 0 is never used.  I can't tell if these would have any affect with 1000 x 1000, but it couldn't hurt to clean up.

Comment: Also, those `else continue;`'s are not needed here (and harmless).  It would just be simpler without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to avoid recursion while not changing the logic of the program is to use a stack data-structure directly, instead of through the call-stack.

Here's a modified version of your Blob class that uses [std::stack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) in your form function:

```
class Blob
{
public:
    long long int pow;

    Blob(int i, int j)
    {
        this->pow = 0;
        point po;
        po.x=i;
        po.y=j;
        this->form(po);
    }

    int getPow()
    {
        return this->pow;
    }

    void form (point p)
    {
        std::stack<point> s;
        s.push(p);

        while (!s.empty())
        {
            p=s.top();
            s.pop();

            if (!inBounds(p))
                continue;

            if(a[p.x][p.y] == '#' && !pat[p.x][p.y])
            {
                a[p.x][p.y] = 1;
                this->pow++;
                point e;
                e.x = p.x-1;    e.y =  p.y;     if(pat[e.x][e.y] == 0)s.push(e);
                e.x = p.x+1;    e.y =  p.y;     if(pat[e.x][e.y] == 0)s.push(e);
                e.x = p.x+1;    e.y =  p.y+1;   if(pat[e.x][e.y] == 0)s.push(e);
                e.x = p.x-1;    e.y =  p.y-1;   if(pat[e.x][e.y] == 0)s.push(e);
                e.x = p.x-1;    e.y =  p.y+1;   if(pat[e.x][e.y] == 0)s.push(e);
                e.x = p.x+1;    e.y =  p.y-1;   if(pat[e.x][e.y] == 0)s.push(e);
                e.x = p.x;      e.y =  p.y-1;   if(pat[e.x][e.y] == 0)s.push(e);
                e.x = p.x;      e.y =  p.y+1;   if(pat[e.x][e.y] == 0)s.push(e);
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Note that this also fixes your memory leak.

In general, the problem you are trying to solve seems to be finding "connected components" with a square-shaped neighborhood. Usually, you'd use a [disjoint-set data-structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to solve this, which does not need a stack or recursion.With that, you can just scan thru the field once and you have the sizes of all your connected components, not just the one where you check for a blob.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the integer matrix `pat[][]` is initialized to all zeros, tested in several places, but never set to anything else.  So the Blob constructor calls `form()` which calls itself almost unconditionally, until there is a crash.  I say "almost" because there are other conditions leading up to the recursive call, but the last check (a value in `pat`) always succeeds.

I could have read too fast, and if so, I will take my beating humbly.  ;-)

Comment: a[x][y] is set to 1 for visited nodes and thus never visited again, since only the "#" ones are visited.

Comment: @ltjax, Yes, you are quite right.  On closer inspection, I see that "visit mark" is done well (right away, unconditionally) when discovered.  `pat` still seems to serve no purpose, but I no longer suspect it is doing any harm, either.